# Android GridView not showing images

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter

I have made a `GridView` with an `ImageAdapter` but it does not show the images inside.
I tried to change `numColumns`, `columnWidth` and other attributes but it didn't work.
In Android Studio xml Design panel i can see my Gridview.

This is my `gridview` inside my `xml` layout file:

```
 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_buttons"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:columnWidth="120dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

This is my Adapter:

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final Context mContext;

public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) { 
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(R.dimen.grid_dimens_width, R.dimen.grid_dimens_height));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setPadding(1, 5, 1, 1);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

private final Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.grid_agapis, R.drawable.grid_asteies, R.drawable.grid_auto,
        R.drawable.grid_gamos, R.drawable.grid_goneis,
};
```

I set the adapter with the following code:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new CustomGridViewAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Can you explain me where is the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you also add the code where you are instantiating the adapter and using it?

Comment: try to replace `setImageResource()` with `setBackgroundResource()`

Comment: now there is a black box at the gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(R.dimen.grid_dimens_width,
                                                    R.dimen.grid_dimens_height));
```

With this line of code you are trying to limit the size of the grabbed drawable to a fixed width & height that are equal to `grid_dimens_width` & `grid_dimens_height` respectively.

But actually using `R.dimen.foo` won't return the value of `foo`, instead it returns the generated integer value of the resource itself which can be something like a big number (e.g. -21893103 or 33238590) .. this will make you see nothing on the screen because the image is either:

- Too big (in case of a positive resource value 33238590) so you are seeing the tiny pixels of it
- or too small (in case of a negative resource value -21893103) because its size is zero.

What you need to do instead is to get the `dimen` resource using [`getDimention()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getDimension(int)) and pass the resource id to it.

To apply that to your code:

Replace:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(R.dimen.grid_dimens_width,
                                                    R.dimen.grid_dimens_height));
```

With:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                  (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.grid_dimens_width),
                  (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.grid_dimens_height)));
```

**Result:**

[image]